# C++ <int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >’ requested?? on a simple 20 line program

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I've been trying to compile and have played around with the ampersands and still can't figure out what the error is. Any ideas?

the following is the only compiling error that I've been getting.

```
 error: conversion from ‘void’ to non-scalar type ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >’ requested
```

and the line that's causing the error is

```
    iterator it2 = nth_element (v_best.begin(), v_best.begin()+n, v_best.end());
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: I recommend looking up `nth_element` online and make the connection on why it doesn't work yourself.

Comment: There is also the matter of a minor typo (you've defined `it2`, but attempted to use `it3` instead).

Comment: Also, there are two `return` statements. Also, you sort everything, there's no point in calling `nth_element` if it's already sorted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element)'s pretty clear, isn't it? `std::nth_element` returns `void`, yet you're trying to initialise an iterator from it. I suspect that you did not actually mean to use `std::nth_element`, which is a partial sorting algorithm.

If you're trying to actually print the *n*<sup>th</sup> element, then this partial sorting algorithm has nothing to do with that goal and you should instead simply, well, access the *n*<sup>th</sup> element! Like so:

```
std::cout << v_best[n] << '\n';
```

If you *did* mean to use this algorithm, then it's not clear what you're trying to accomplish with this `it2` (later typo'd as `it3`). What element are you trying to print? Do you realise you `return`ed from the function first, anyway?

You could just write:

```
nth_element(v_best.begin(), v_best.begin()+n, v_best.end());
```

then accomplish your "printing" goal, whatever that may be, in some other way.

Answer (score 0):

The [nth_element function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) returns `void`. However you try to convert this to an `iterator`.

To fix this just get rid of `it2`.

Also you have code after the `return` statement, which is unreachable (and uses an undeclared identifier `it3`).